# context deadline exceeded when check etcd health

Tags: kubernetes

I am check etcd(3.3.13) cluster status using this command:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z work]# /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl endpoint health --cluster
https://172.19.150.82:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
https://172.19.104.231:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
https://172.19.104.230:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
Error: unhealthy cluster
```

check etcd member:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z work]# /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl member list
    56298c42af788da7, started, azshara-k8s02, https://172.19.104.230:2380, https://172.19.104.230:2379
    5ab2d0e431f00a20, started, azshara-k8s01, https://172.19.104.231:2380, https://172.19.104.231:2379
    84c70bf96ccff30f, started, azshara-k8s03, https://172.19.150.82:2380, https://172.19.150.82:2379
```

my cluster is deploy success?If not,how to solve the context deadline exceeded error? I tried this:

```
     export ETCDCTL_API=3
     [root@ops001 ~]# /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl endpoint status --write-out=table
+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|    ENDPOINT    |        ID        | VERSION | DB SIZE | IS LEADER | RAFT TERM | RAFT INDEX |
+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 127.0.0.1:2379 | 5ab2d0e431f00a20 |  3.3.13 |  2.0 MB |     false |        20 |   39303798 |
+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
[root@ops001 ~]# /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl endpoint health
127.0.0.1:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 1.816293ms
[root@ops001 ~]# /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl endpoint health --cluster
https://172.19.150.82:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
https://172.19.104.231:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
https://172.19.104.230:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded
Error: unhealthy cluster
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how to solve the context deadline exceeded error?

That error is misleading; it is *usually* caused by `etcdctl` not providing credentials and/or not using the same `ETCDCTL_API=` value as the cluster. If it's a modern `etcd` version, you'll want [`export ETCDCTL_API=3`](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.0/Documentation/dev-guide/interacting_v3.md), followed by providing the same [`--cert-file=` and `--key-file=` and likely `--trusted-ca-file=`](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.0/Documentation/op-guide/security.md#basic-setup) as was used to start `etcd` itself.

Comment: We had this on a `defrag` operation and, in that case, increasing the command timeout (default 5s) with `--command-timeout=120s` helped. I don't think it is directly relevant to your issue but worth mentioning

Comment: Thank you mdaniel, that is very misleading error being returned. I wonder if there are existing issues file with regards for this error. But thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The error is indeed misleading, I faced the same problem due to whitespace issue in command, [see my answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1091649/etcdctl-endpoint-health-unhealty/1155640#1155640):

```bash
kubectl -nkube-system exec -it etcd-k8s-cp -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3
ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
etcdctl endpoint health"
# 127.0.0.1:2379 is unhealthy: failed to commit proposal
# Error: unhealthy cluster

# VS

kubectl -nkube-system exec -it etcd-k8s-cp -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3 \
ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key \
etcdctl endpoint health"
# 127.0.0.1:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal
# Success
```